# Python3 generate strings in for-loop, class variables not being redefined for each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to generate a list of emails from a list of employees (each employee in an embedded list of their own). This is done by first choosing the format of the email and then using a for-loop over each employee's name. Below is the code. My problem is that if I give self.first and self.last empty strings so that they can be called in the choice of format below, they aren't reassigned actual first and last names in the for-loop but rather the emails are printed with their empty strings. I see that the method for getting a first and last name works but for some reason the email = self.email_format isn't working properly with an output (or a similar output) of:

['*@gmail.com', '*@gmail.com', '_@gmail.com']

How can I fix this or rearrange the data?

```
class email_generator():

    def __init__(self):
        self.domain = 'gmail'
        self.generated_emails = []
        self.employees = [['Foo Bar', 'job title'], ['Matthew Gorand', 'job title'], ['Julia Snyder', 'job title']]

    def format_choice(self):
        self.last = ''
        self.first = ''
        choice = input('''
                Choose a format for generating emails:

                1) first.last@domain.com
                2) last.f@domain.com
                3) f.last@domain.com
                4) last_first@domain.com
                5) firstl@domain.com
                6) flast@domain.com
                7) Pass
                ''')

        if choice == '1':
            self.email_format = f'{self.first}.{self.last}@{self.domain}.com'
        elif choice == '2':
            self.email_format = f'{self.last}.{self.first}@{self.domain}.com'
        elif choice == '3':
            self.email_format = f'{self.first[:1]}.{self.last}@{self.domain}.com'
        elif choice == '4':
            self.email_format = f'{self.last}_{self.first}@{self.domain}.com'
        elif choice == '5':
            self.email_format = f'{self.first}.{self.last[:1]}@{self.domain}.com'
        elif choice == '6':
            self.email_format = f'{self.first[:1]}{self.last}@{self.domain}.com'
        elif choice == '7':
            pass
        else:
            print('Invalid Input')
            self.format_choice()

        for employee in self.employees:
            split = employee[0].split(' ')
            self.first = split[0]
            self.last = split[1]
            email = self.email_format
            self.generated_emails.append(email)

        print(self.generated_emails)

test = email_generator()
test.format_choice()
```

Comment: please use the generic [python] tag for *all* python questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `f-strings` is nice, they are interpolated immediately and do not help you due to your structuring of code. `str.format()` however does:

```
class email_generator(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.domain = 'gmail'
        self.generated_emails = []
        self.employees = [['Foo Bar', 'job title'], ['Matthew Gorand', 'job title'], 
                          ['Julia Snyder', 'job title']]
```

Choose what format to use is handeled in its own function now:

```
    def get_format(self):
        """Loops until a valid choice was made, returns a format string using f,l and d
        as variable names for first,last and domain."""
        while True:
            choice = input('''
    Choose a format for generating emails:

    1) first.last@domain.com
    2) last.f@domain.com
    3) f.last@domain.com
    4) last_first@domain.com
    5) firstl@domain.com
    6) flast@domain.com
    7) Pass
    ''')

            if choice == '1':
                return '{f}.{l}@{d}.com' 
            elif choice == '2':
                return '{l}.{f[0]}@{d}.com' 
            elif choice == '3':
                return '{f[0]}.{l}@{d}.com' 
            elif choice == '4':
                return '{l}_{f}@{d}.com' 
            elif choice == '5':
                return '{f}.{l[0]}@{d}.com' 
            elif choice == '6':
                return '{f[0]}{l}@{d}.com'
            elif choice == '7':
                return None

        print("Invalid.")
```

The formatter itself - shortened because the format-string chooser was refactured into its own function:

```
    def format_choice(self):
        email_format = self.get_format()
        if not email_format:
            return

        for employee in self.employees:
            split = employee[0].split(' ')
            fir = split[0]
            las = split[1]
            dom = self.domain
            # the str.format can use positional or named formatting - I use named
            # this must correlate with the names inside the format string:
            #                   '{f[0]}.{l}@{d}.com'     --> f=fir, l=las, d=dom 
            self.generated_emails.append(email_format.format(f=fir, l=las, d=dom))

        print(self.generated_emails)

test = email_generator() 
test.format_choice() # 6 times for all different formats to get all outputs
```

Output:

```
# 1
['Foo.Bar@gmail.com', 'Matthew.Gorand@gmail.com', 'Julia.Snyder@gmail.com']
# 2
['Bar.F@gmail.com', 'Gorand.M@gmail.com', 'Snyder.J@gmail.com']
# 3
['F.Bar@gmail.com', 'M.Gorand@gmail.com', 'J.Snyder@gmail.com']
# 4
['Bar_Foo@gmail.com', 'Gorand_Matthew@gmail.com', 'Snyder_Julia@gmail.com']
# 5
['Foo.B@gmail.com', 'Matthew.G@gmail.com', 'Julia.S@gmail.com']
# 6
['FBar@gmail.com', 'MGorand@gmail.com', 'JSnyder@gmail.com']
```

There is no need for `self.first` or `self.last` - simple function scope parameters are enough.